# Run time error when reading file: Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'delta_c' was corrupted

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, runtime-error

I got a strange running error when reading a file using C, The error message is "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'delta_c' was corrupted." I'm using visual studio 2010

Here is the simplified version of code I'm running error with(I got running error even on this simplified version)

```
#include "stdafx.h"

typedef struct {
    unsigned short dx;  
    unsigned short dy;
    unsigned char  dr;  
    unsigned short ext; 
    unsigned char delta_c; 
} Delta;

typedef struct {
    unsigned char   region;     
    unsigned char   delta_num;  
    Delta       delta[8];   
} MNTDATSTRUCT;
int ReadAr(const char* mntfile, MNTDATSTRUCT *p)   
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(mntfile, "r");

    fscanf(fp, "%u",&p->delta_num);
    for (int i=0; i<p->delta_num; ++i) {
        unsigned short dx, dy, ext;
        unsigned char delta_c;
        fscanf(fp,"%u%u%u%u", &dx, &dy, &ext, &delta_c);
        p->delta[i].dx = dx;
        p->delta[i].dy = dy;
        p->delta[i].ext = ext;
        p->delta[i].delta_c = delta_c;

    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    MNTDATSTRUCT p;
    ReadAr("F:\\projects\\test_c++\\Debug\\tt.bpm",&p);
    return 0;
}
```

The data file I planned to read(i.e tt.bpm) looks like this:

```
1 
1 2 10 13
```

Note for some reasons, some field of struct Delta was not shown on the data file(unsigned char dr). Also for unsigned char region in struct MNTDATSTRUCT

When I trying to run the code, Visual studio will stop at line33(just after return 0 from ReadAr), and pop out an run time error message: Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'delta_c' was corrupted.", although in watch window, MNTDATSTRUCT *p has been property filled.

I'm curious about this situation. Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Thank for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `h` modifier for short ints and use the `hh` chars.

```
fscanf(fp, "%hhu",&p->delta_num);
…
fscanf(fp,"%hu%hu%hu%hhu", &dx, &dy, &ext, &delta_c);
```